# Does python have such commands as "union()" and "connected()"?

Tags: java, python, union

I took some Coursera course about Algorithms. Code to algorithms in this course is on Java. There were some Java math commands called `union()` and `connected()`. `union()` command connecting numbers, variables... and `connected()` command is checking the connection. For example:

```
>>>union(3, 4)
>>>union(5, 8)
>>>connected(3, 4)
True
>>>connected(5, 4)
False
```

So my question is:

> Does python have such commands as **union()** and **connected()**?

Thanks.

Comment: Check http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union

Comment: Sounds like union and connected are methods of some kind of tree they implemented.

Comment: Reference for other people reading this : https://class.coursera.org/algs4partI-003/lecture/index

The lectures does provide you some Java implementation that you can freely re-adapt in Python.